# Publishing [part] of ASP.NET MVC Core application to web host

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc

The situation is such, I am able to successfully publish my application live to the web host via Visual Studio 2018 FTP publishing option and it connects and publishes it correctly and the changes are visible.

However, there are a few folders which are stored on the server which contain several audio files, so every time I publish the audio files are deleted and and than republished. Not only is the process too long, it is redundant. And since and ASP.NET Core converts the application to dll files, it is faster on the clients end, but posting changes is a nightmare, since all the files have to be deleted including the audio folder and re-uploaded.

The csproj file looks like this :

```
    <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

      <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
      </PropertyGroup>

      <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|AnyCPU'">
        <DebugType>full</DebugType>
        <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
      </PropertyGroup>

      <ItemGroup>
        <Content Remove="Views\Shared\ExplainPage.cshtml" />
      </ItemGroup>

      <ItemGroup>
        <None Remove="Properties\PublishProfiles\CustomProfile.pubxml" />
        <None Remove="Properties\PublishProfiles\CustomProfile1.pubxml" />
        <None Remove="Properties\PublishProfiles\umaraftab.net - Web Deploy.pubxml" />
      </ItemGroup>

      <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies" Version="2.0.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity" Version="2.0.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="2.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.ViewCompilation" Version="2.0.0" PrivateAssets="All" />
      </ItemGroup>

      <ItemGroup>
        <Folder Include="Properties\PublishProfiles\" />
        <Folder Include="wwwroot\explanations\" />
        <Folder Include="wwwroot\lectures\" />
      </ItemGroup>

      <ItemGroup>
        <None Include="wwwroot\slick\fonts\slick.svg" />
      </ItemGroup>

    </Project>
```

The wwwroot\lectures and wwwroot\explanation folders contain the audio files. 
Would anyone be able to advice on how I can just let the audio folders stay as-is on the server and just recreate the dll files and upload them, as that is where the changes are.

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing those 2 folders in the csproj with the remove keyword :

```
    <Folder Remove="wwwroot\explanations\" />
    <Folder Remove="wwwroot\lectures\" />
```

And during publish, do not delete files in the destination folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude these folders from the project. Update the .csproj file to remove the following two lines of code:

```
 <Folder Include="wwwroot\explanations\" />
 <Folder Include="wwwroot\lectures\" />
```

You can edit the .csproj directly inside Visual Studio by right clicking project node in solution explorer and then edit.